# Redirect all url's with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm stuck with this problem for a while. But i want to redirect all my pages without a # to URL with # see the example below. This example works for one page but i would like to get this for all my pages in one time.

```
RewriteEngine on 
Redirect permanent /index.php/artikel/contact http://www.mydomain.com/#index.php/artikel/contact
```

Is there a way to insert a variable or something like so i don't have to insert my urls one by one?

Thank you already again for your time.

Comment: Hope you understand that URI with `#` doesn't even reach up to Apache. It is all handled within browser.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use mod_rewrite. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Then, instead of specifying each url with Redirect (which may not even need the rewrite engine), you can use the paringin

```
RewriteCond
RewriteRule
```

to specify conditions using regular expressions.